# VSTO add-in silent installation

Tags: vsto, ms-office, clickonce, add-on

I've developed a VSTO addin with VS2012 signed by a DigiCert certificate. I need to deploy it to all the Enterprise users so the installer shouldn't prompt the user because it will fail since all the installation process is silent.
I'm not able to do it since it always ask the user if it should or shouldn't install. If I set VSTOInstaller /S it doesn't install 'silently'.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks on advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. To solve this you have to install the public key certificate in your installer:

`certutil -addstore TRUSTEDPUBLISHER "yourcertificate.cer"`

Then, you just use VSTOInstaller:

`VSTOInstaller.exe /I "youraddin.vsto" /S`

That's all folks!

Comment: I also saw this solution, nevertheless that shouldn't be necessary... Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Just Uncheck the ClickOnce manifest CheckBox and Check the signing the assembly using any .snk file.

You will need to create installer project and the rebuild the installer project will provide you the .msi and .exe file you can execute the following command on command prompt(Administator).

Though rebuilding of installer project will automatically check the ClickOnce checkBox but you can ignore that.

Below is the link for creating Installer project for AddIn.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ff937654(v=msdn.10)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to GPO for deploying the software (using MSI installers).

- [How to use Group Policy to remotely install software in Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816102)
- [How to use Windows Installer and Group Policy to deploy the VPModule.msi in an Active Directory domain](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/887405)
- [Installing Software Using GPO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXAz6vrWMP0)

Also see the [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) section in MSDN.

Comment: I can't use GPO. I've inherited a Inno Setup project and the product is huge, this part is a small part and it should be installed in machines which lack of domain controller and can't be pushed to install software by GPO